# How do I initialise values of a struct object when dynamically allocating a multidimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct

I've been trying to find out what's wrong, I just can't see it.
It's a Minesweeper grid, I'm trying to allocate memory for a 2D array of pointers to objects of type struct Cell, with its values set.
When I use this function, I get a grid of cells from which I can ask their values, but those are all NULL.
I know the error lies here, since I used a library that did this allocating for me, and my code worked with that. I have to write the allocation myself now.

```
struct Cell*** allocate_grid(int grid_width, int grid_height) {
    struct Cell*** grid = malloc(grid_width * sizeof(*grid));
    int column;
    for (column = 0; column < grid_width; column++) {
        grid[column] = malloc(grid_height * sizeof(**grid));
        int row;
        for (row = 0; row < grid_height; row++) {
            struct Cell cell = {COVERED, 0, false}; //state, neighbouring mines, is_mine
            grid[column][row] = &cell;
      }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually allocate memory for the cell itself, using malloc.

```
struct Cell* alloc_cell(enum State state, int neighbouring_mines, bool is_mine) {
    struct Cell* cell = malloc(sizeof(cell));
    cell->state = state;
    cell->neighbouring_mines = neighbouring_mines;
    cell->is_mine = is_mine;
    return cell;
}

struct Cell*** allocate_grid(int grid_width, int grid_height) {
    struct Cell*** grid = malloc(grid_width * sizeof(*grid));
    int column;
    for (column = 0; column < grid_width; column++) {
        grid[column] = malloc(grid_height * sizeof(**grid));
        int row;
        for (row = 0; row < grid_height; row++) {
            grid[column][row] = alloc_cell(COVERED, 0, false);
      }
    }
    return grid;
}
```